# TYPO3 Extbase: clearState not freeing memory

Tags: memory, typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I have an import job for scheduler written with Extbase and memory usage is really high.
In TYPO3 7.6, I was able to free memory with

```
$this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager::class)->clearState();
```

But after upgrading to TYPO3 9.5, "clearState" seems not to work like before, this function just frees a tiny amount of memory.

I've written a simple example code which demonstrates the problem. This example can run in a Extbase Controller, no need to run it in Scheduler context.

```
var_dump(memory_get_usage());
$v1 = $this->frontendUserRepository->findAll();
foreach($v1 as $vv1) {
    $a1 = $this->frontendUserRepository->findOneByUid($vv1->getUid());
}
var_dump(memory_get_usage());
$this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager::class)->clearState();
var_dump(memory_get_usage());
```

Output is `int(49013528) int(565877768) int(543894472)`: Retrieving users from the database by "findOneByUid" consumes much memory, because the objects are stored in some PHP variable and I like to free this memory. In TYPO3 7, this worked with function "clearState".

Comment: According to your change of the question and the new code-example: `$v1` holds all `fe_users` as objects and `$a1` at time of your 2nd `var_dump` holds the last record of `fe_users` still another time. I can't see that the data are loaded on persistence-level, so I think it's reasonable that the memory usage is 565877768.
You could debug the memory usage before the loop too. If you just want data fetched by `findOneByUid($uid)` then you should make `$a` an array or `objectStorage`-object and load there all records, afterwards you can destroy `$v1`.

Comment: Nevetheless, I never assume less memory usage after that than now. Also I don't see a reason to load data first with `findAll()` and after that still with `findByUid()`.

Comment: If you want to keep the general structure (no matter about the sense), then write a repository-function that first is getting only the `uid`s in `$v1` and not all data with it. This data-amount is much smaller and then it's not of much impact concerning memory-usage.

Comment: Concerning my answer and your example: if you've much data, you're processing the whole stack in once. I don't know about the usage after your loop but if it's possible make chunks of 100 or 1000 records and process chunk by chunk including freeing the memory after being processed. Assume you had a endless stream that would be impossible to save on disc and you had to process it eternally.

Comment: @David: This is just an example code, to demonstrate the issue with "clearState". This is no code I want to optimize. I just want to free some memory during script execution. I already made chunks and every chunk I call "clearState" and this worked in TYPO3 7.6 but not in TYPO3 9.5.

Comment: I've written a bug report for this: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/89845

Comment: I'm assuming that the old behavior was based on a bug which is probably fixed in current versions. That would mean that in older versions too much data have been written in persistence-level or it deleted too much.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method you're using:

```
    /**
     * Clears the in-memory state of the persistence.
     *
     * Managed instances become detached, any fetches will
     * return data directly from the persistence "backend".
     *
     * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Exception\NotImplementedException
     * @internal only to be used within Extbase, not part of TYPO3 Core API.
     */
    public function clearState()
    {
        $this->newObjects = [];
        $this->addedObjects = new ObjectStorage();
        $this->removedObjects = new ObjectStorage();
        $this->changedObjects = new ObjectStorage();
        $this->persistenceSession->destroy();
    }
```

So in my opinion it's not useful to call it at all as it's just clearing any stack that would be processed with `persistAll()` I assume. If a stack like that shall be cleared, why it should be written first?
Perhaps I'm missing the sense of the function but at least it doesn't indeed delete much data usually.
I'd use the function in an extension perhaps if it turns out that some condition shall reset any prepared database-operations, but that's nothing for a scheduler task and should depend on special conditions instead of systematically just deleting the stack completely.

Question is which kind of cache you want to delete, [here is a list of the cache-API](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/Architecture/Index.html#cache-api).
And here is still mentioned about the [Garbage Collection Task](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/Architecture/Index.html#garbage-collection-task), perhaps that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi David, after calling persistAll() I do a clearState() to free memory. The scheduler job runs over an hour and handles many objects and this helped to not consume too much memory. Now, in TYPO3 9, this import job consumes 13 GB of memory and more. Destroying persistenceSession surely freed most of memory, because there all the data I retrieved from database were stored, but there seems to be an issue in TYPO3 9 with this.

Comment: @Sven, being astonished that it was required, as I'd assume that after persisting memory would be cleaned automatically concerning the related objects. But honestly I don't know in the moment and had to look up. In my opinion an import job consuming so much memory is not useful and should be rewritten to work sequential including the cleanup of memory after each sequence if required. The scheduler job would be superfluous then.

Comment: Hi David, I retrieve many records from the database via the repository classes and TYPO3 stores them in some persistence layer ($this->persistenceSession), persisting (that means updating/inserting the changed/new object in the database) doesn't remove the objects from it. I will add some more code to my question.